# Is there a function similar to setInterval () (JavaScript) for PHP?

Tags: php

I just started with php. So can I do something similar to "setInterval" with php?

```
function setInterval($fn, $timeout){
    // for $timeout milliseconds.
}
```

Comment: Not really. You can use multi-threading.

Comment: Why would you want to? Your reason stated in plain words may help with an idea or suggestions in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing exactly like **setInterval()**, Because you **can't** keep running your **back-end** operation continuously for a request. You need to send back the response to the browser, Otherwise the browser will throw **Timeout Error**, Meanwhile PHP will throw **Maximum Execution time / memory Exceed Error**.

**BUT**

If you want to do an action for every specific time interval. You can do it using [Cron Jobs](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/schedule-cron-jobs-in-php/), But it will be separated from **Http Request**.

If you want to do an action along with your HTTP Request, Then you can trigger [XMLHTTP Request (Ajax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to your **PHP End-Point** for every specific time interval using **setTimeout**.

---

> **NOTE:** Specifying what you want to archive will help us to provide best method.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I have found a solution with your answer